# Obtain value of previously executed prepared statement in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have used a prepared statement to set a variable as follows:

```
$CPI = $cxn->prepare('SET @CPI = ?');
$CPI->bind_param('d', $_POST['CPI_Esc']);
$CPI->execute();
```

I would now like to access the value of @CPI in later php script without using  `$_POST['CPI_Esc'].`  I have tried the following as it makes sense in terms of MySQL:

```
$Check = "SELECT @CPI";
$Check = mysqli_query($cxn, $CPI);
echo $Check . " CPI value";
```

I am pretty sure the `mysqli_query()` is the wrong function to use here - I am not sure which to use or whether I am approaching this the wrong way.  I just want to create a variable in php that I can use later based on the value of my previously executed prepared statement. Any thoughts?

Comment: Even if you can use`mysqli_query` you still need to fetch yes?

Comment: Hi @AbraCadaver, I just need to get the value of '@CPI' as set by the prepared statement.  I don't mind what the function is, as long as it works I guess.

Comment: What is the reason for that strange requirement?

Comment: I am not sure what the strange requirement you are referring to is @Paul Spiegel.  If it is why I want to get a variable to use later in php and not just use `$_POST['CPI_Esc']` it is because I then use that value later when querying a table.  I figure that it has already gone through the prepared statement process and so I am trying to avoid doing it again later.

Comment: _"in later php"_ - what do you mean with that? the same (or an included) script, just later in the script, or another script 5 minutes _later_? But from what I expect a `$_SESSION` would be a good choice.

Comment: If you want to use it in another query then do it like "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE cpi = @CPI" (though it doesn't look like a good idea). I don't see a reason to fetch it.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to create a variable in php that I can use later

Each PHP run is a separate process which has its own variable scope not shared among other processes. To store a value to be accessed from different runs you'll need some external storage. Here are some:

- A table in a database, such as MySQL or MongoDB or whatever.
- A file on disk.
- APC cache.
- Memcache or Redis.

If both runs share a session id (for example, you access them from the browser by refreshing the same page or by navigating your site) then you can take advantage of PHP's built-in session storage and `$_SESSION` variable. Please read further: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php as your mileage may vary.

**UPD.** A very brief introduction to how you use session variables to access data between different requests to the same page.

1. Put this on top of your php script:

   ```
   session_start();
   ```
2. Store the value under some key with a usual array assignment:

   ```
   $_SESSION['CPI'] = $_POST['CPI_Esc'];
   ```
3. Access it later with a usual array dereference:

   ```
   echo "CPI value: {$_SESSION['CPI']}\n";
   ```

Under usual circumstances* this should work for you.

* Usual circumstances include: unchanged php configuration; sufficient permissions for php process to write to the sessions directory; your browser accepts cookies.

Comment: Thank you guys for this.  I had not used $_SESSION variables before and I really appreciate the run down.  My code is in a single php page and using variables later on has been fine.  How can I then place the value as set by  'Set @CPI = ' into such a variable without querying a table as Paul Spiegel suggests?  I can't query a table as CPI is used in calculations within a MySQL procedure.  Thanks everyone for your input.